# C# MVC Syntax - Recursive seeking in a template lambda (EditorFor)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, lambda, mvc-editor-templates

I have a recursive model.

```
public class Mapping
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<Mapping> ChildMappings { get; set; }
}
```

I have an EditorTemplate for the Mapping class. Normal rendering via EditorFor( m => m.ChildMappings) works fine.

Based on an array parameter (2,3), I'd like to seek a specific descendant node. (Mapping.ChildMappings[2].ChildMappings[3] for example).

I've tried calling a local method within the lambda, which gave me an error about indexers and all the things I can't do in a template.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => RecurseMappings(m.BodyMappings, indexes))

@functions{
    private Mapping RecurseMappings(List<Mapping> mappings, int[] indexes)
    {
        Mapping mapping = new Mapping();

        foreach (int index in indexes)
        {
            mapping = mappings[index];
            if (mapping.ChildMappings == null) { mapping.ChildMappings = new List<RequestMapping>(); }
            mappings = mappings[index].ChildMappings;
        }

        return mappings[mappings.Count - 1];
    }
```

For the moment I've fallen back on a switch to at least facilitate a hard coded number of nested levels, like this:

```
    string[] tokens = Model.ChildIndex.Split(',');
    int[] indexes = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(tokens, int.Parse);

   switch (indexes.GetLength(0))
    {
        case 1:
            {
                var last = Model.BodyMappings[indexes[0]].ChildMappings.Count - 1;
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BodyMappings[indexes[0]].ChildMappings[last])
                break;
            }

        case 2:
            {
                var last = Model.BodyMappings[indexes[0]].ChildMappings[indexes[1]].ChildMappings.Count - 1;
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BodyMappings[indexes[0]].ChildMappings[indexes[1]].ChildMappings[last])
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                var last = Model.BodyMappings[indexes[0]].ChildMappings[indexes[1]].ChildMappings[indexes[2]].ChildMappings.Count - 1;
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BodyMappings[indexes[0]].ChildMappings[indexes[1]].ChildMappings[indexes[2]].ChildMappings[last])
                break;
            }
        case 4:
            {
                var last = Model.BodyMappings[indexes[0]].ChildMappings[indexes[1]].ChildMappings[indexes[2]].ChildMappings[indexes[3]].ChildMappings.Count - 1;
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BodyMappings[indexes[0]].ChildMappings[indexes[1]].ChildMappings[indexes[2]].ChildMappings[indexes[3]].ChildMappings[last])
                break;
            }
        case 5:
            {
                var last = Model.BodyMappings[indexes[0]].ChildMappings[indexes[1]].ChildMappings[indexes[2]].ChildMappings[indexes[3]].ChildMappings[indexes[4]].ChildMappings.Count - 1;
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BodyMappings[indexes[0]].ChildMappings[indexes[1]].ChildMappings[indexes[2]].ChildMappings[indexes[3]].ChildMappings[indexes[4]].ChildMappings[last])
                break;
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
```

So, Is there a way to wrap up what I have working in a package more like my failed first attempt? I've also tried a lambda code block, only to be denied because it can't be converted to an expression tree.

Answer (score 1):

Well, probably this is not the intended way, but it works when you create a new Html-Helper for the object you want to pick:

```
@{  
    var dd =  new ViewDataDictionary<Mapping>(RecurseMappings(Model.BodyMappings, indexes));
    var dc = new MyDataContainer() { ViewData = dd };
    var help = new HtmlHelper<Mapping>(ViewContext, dc);
}

@help.EditorFor(m => m)
```

In a source file the definition of a custom data container, since I could not find a class that implements the interface.

```
public class MyDataContainer : IViewDataContainer
{
    public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is giving me the same runtime error (debugging indicates it does not even attempt to enter the method).
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: This feels closer, as it is not breaking, but is serving multiple elements (all in hierarchy) and somewhat incorrect model binding. The result needs to bind back to the top parent by name or it cant be posted as a "BodyMappings" collection component of a parent model.